# Plugin or code snippet for Nodejs optional regex named group

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Lines of Strings

```
line 1 = [A B C]
line 2 = [A C]
line 3 = [B C]
```

Regular Expression

```
/\[?(?<groupA>[A])?(?:[ ]*)?(?<groupB>[B])?(?:[ ]*)?(?<groupC>[C])\]/gm
```

How can I achieve the following behavior using either plugin or code snippet?

line 1

```
result.groupA = A
result.groupB = B
result.groupC = C
```

line 2

```
result.groupA = A
result.groupB = null/undefined
result.groupC = C
```

line 3

```
result.groupA = null/undefined
result.groupB = B
result.groupC = C
```

I have tried named-js-regexp npm package, however the package depends on

```
var matched = RegExp.prototype.exec.call()
```

which returns a match where the position of the undefined/unmatched group cannot be identified.

The implementation found on https://regex101.com/r/aD2sZ3/1 however works perfectly. 
Note: the javascript code generated by regex101 does not work in nodejs due to bundled regex missing support for named groups.

Update: XRegExp package works as expected for this purpose. We can also use the solution from answers below, then enumerate the "named" capture manually.

Comment: Any particular reason for using regex here?

Comment: @Ammar This is regex will used to parse openstack logs. 
2016-03-07 11:19:33.712 WARNING oslo_reports.guru_meditation_report [-] Guru mediation now registers SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 by default for backward compatibility. SIGUSR1 will no longer be registered in a future release, so please use SIGUSR2 to generate reports.
[id1 id2 id3] or [-], I'd like to know which ID is missing or entire id set is missing using regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove group name? Then check what is missing by index.

```
var re = /\[?([A])?(?:\s*)?([B])?(?:\s*)?([C])\]/gm; 
var str = '[C]';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m[1] == null){
        console.log('Missing A');
    };
    if (m[2] == null){
        console.log('Missing B');
    };
    if (m[3] == null){
        console.log('Missing B');
    };
}
```